# Specific PHP session variables disappearing only in Firefox - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, firefox

I am setting two session variables from post values in a controller. They persist after loading the next view but then are mysteriously set to NULL after another view is loaded. All other session variables are untouched regardless of whether I set them before the controller runs or in the same controller.

```
<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'form-group');
echo form_open('dates_validation', $attributes);?>
    <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker" name="arrival_date"
       style="width:120px" onchange="function1()"><br />
    <label for="departure_date">Departure date:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker2" name="departure_date"
       style="width:120px" onchange="function1()"><br />
```

Controller:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('arrival_date', $_POST['arrival_date']);
$this->session->set_userdata('departure_date', $_POST['departure_date']);
```

I've tried using native sessions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question with you config session set up

Comment: JS is browser's executable code. What is in `function1()`?